# Change switch button color based on alert dialog response

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a flutter package called [https://pub.dev/packages/switcher_button](http://switcher_button) and I would like to change the color of the button from green to red and vice versa when user chooses to cancel their action. I can see that the value changes in the onChange function but the button remains the same. So if I click on  the button and then choose "No" option in the alert dialog, I want the button to revert back to the original status.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final scaffold = Scaffold.of(context);
    bool isSwitchOn = true;
                return ListTile(
                  leading: Text(widget.title),
                  //title:   ,
                  trailing: Container(
                    width: 200,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                    SwitcherButton(
                    value:  isSwitchOn,
            onColor: Colors.greenAccent,
            offColor: Colors.redAccent,
            onChange: (value) {
              print(value);
              AwesomeDialog(
                context: context,
                dialogType: DialogType.QUESTION,
                animType: AnimType.TOPSLIDE,
                title: value==true?'Mark item as availeble ?':'Mark item as unavailable?',
                desc:'hello',
                btnCancelOnPress: () {
                     setState(() {
                   isSwitchOn=!value;
                   print('Value after cancel is ' + isSwitchOn.toString());
                });
                },
                btnOkText: "Yes",
                btnCancelText:"No",
                btnOkOnPress: () {
                  setState(() {
                   
                });
                
                },
              )..show();
            },
          ),
           ],
        ),
      ),
    );
   }
```

Here's the screenshot for visual purposes. When I switch from green to red, an alert dialog appears with two options: Yes and No. If I click No, then the switch button should remain green. IN other words, it should go back to it's original value.

[image]

Comment: Please see my updated question. I am not looking for alert dialog functionality. Rather am looking for changing switch button state.

Comment: no it does not change the color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: Move `bool isSwitchOn = true;` outside `build` 
Step 2: `SwitcherButton` use `UniqueKey()`

```
SwitcherButton(
          key: UniqueKey(),
```

Step 3: `btnOkOnPress` set `isSwitchOn`

```
btnOkOnPress: () {
            setState(() {
              isSwitchOn = value;
            });
          },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:switcher_button/switcher_button.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class CustomSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  CustomSwitch({this.title});
  @override
  _CustomSwitchState createState() => _CustomSwitchState();
}

class _CustomSwitchState extends State<CustomSwitch> {
  bool isSwitchOn = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Text(widget.title),
      //title:   ,
      trailing: Container(
        width: 200,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SwitcherButton(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              value: isSwitchOn,
              onColor: Colors.greenAccent,
              offColor: Colors.redAccent,
              onChange: (value) {
                print(value);
                AwesomeDialog(
                  context: context,
                  dialogType: DialogType.QUESTION,
                  animType: AnimType.TOPSLIDE,
                  title: value == true
                      ? 'Mark item as availeble ?'
                      : 'Mark item as unavailable?',
                  desc: 'hello',
                  btnCancelOnPress: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isSwitchOn = !value;
                      print('Value after cancel is ' + isSwitchOn.toString());
                    });
                  },
                  btnOkText: "Yes",
                  btnCancelText: "No",
                  btnOkOnPress: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isSwitchOn = value;
                    });
                  },
                )..show();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomSwitch(title: "Chicken Burger"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

bool isSwitchOn is set to true every time the build function is called as you have declared it inside the build method.
Declare the bool isSwitchOn outside the build method (Instance variable within the class).

Comment: I tried this but it's still not changing the switch button.